# Como mudar a cor de uma div parent relativamente ao tamanho das childs

Tags: jquery, html, css

Tenho uma `div parent` e 4 `div's child` e gostaria de mudar a cor da `border` da `div parent` relativamente ao tamanho das `div child`. Para exclarecer melhor colocou abaixo uma imagem com um exemplo do que falo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As cores rosa e vermelho são só para exemplificar o tamanho das `divs child` e a border à esquerda pertence à `div parent`. Gostaria que me respondessem em `jquery`.

Edit:

Segue o código solicitado. É a `border` cinzenta da `div parent` que eu quero mudar a cor com o tamanho das suas `divs child`.

```js
$(".timeline").css({
 "border-left" : "5px solid lightgray",
 "padding-left" : "10px"
}).children().css({
 "margin-bottom" : "5px",
 "padding" : "5px",
 "border" : "2px solid black"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timeline">
 <div>
  <bold name="10 3 2017 9:10">Block 1 </bold>
 </div>
 <div>
  <bold name="10 3 2017 10:30">Block 2 </bold>
 </div>
 <div>
  <bold name="10 3 2017 12:30">Block 3 </bold>
 </div>
 <div>
     <bold name="10 3 2017 13:50">Block 4 </bold>
 </div>
</div>
```

Edit 2:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A segunda div começa então acaba a margin.

Comment: Poste o código se possível, fica mais fácil de te ajudarem.

Comment: @BrunoRomualdo editei a pergunta e coloquei o código.

Comment: Só pra entender, você quer que elas mudem no `:hover` ou que sempre estejam com a cor da borda alterada

Comment: Sempre, porém cria apenas com o tamanho de 1 div child

Comment: Entendi, como uma borda mas separada da div certo?

Comment: Ja te mando um JsFiddle perae ;)

Comment: Só mais uma pergunta, pra que precisa da borda cinza se ela vai ser cobrida?

Comment: Isso é para fazer uma especie de timeline em que preciso da borda cinza para a dita timeline e quero que fique doutra cor quando a etapa esteja completa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `css` para fazer isso.
deixe suas `divs` de dentro da classe `.timeline` com `position: relative`

```
div.timeline > div {
  position: relative;
}
```

e com um `pseudo elemento` `::after` ou `::before` voce pode fazer uma borda 'fake' e estilizá-la como quiser e css

```
div.timeline > div::before {
  content: '';
  width: 5px;
  height: 135%;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: -17px;
  top: -2px;
}
```

Veja esse [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r6dq5cf9/2/) que fiz como exemplo.

Comment: Será possivel fazer com que o height da margin que mudamos a cor fosse até ao topo da div de baixo?

Comment: Desculpa não entendi direito sua dúvida pode explicar?

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta para ser mais específico. :)

Comment: Você quer que a borda falsa (preta) cubra toda a borda cinza?

Comment: Eu quero que a borda preta acabe onde começa a segunda div, que tem borda cinza, é isso que me está a dar problemas.

Comment: Vou atualizar o JSFiddle e o css da resposta.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66537/discussion-between-bruno-romualdo-and-bruno-gibellino).

Answer (score 1):

Funcionalidade interessante!

Podias fazer isso assim:

```js
const divs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('body > div'));
// máximo de children
const max = Math.max.apply(Math.max, divs.map(div => div.children.length));

divs.forEach(div => {
  div.style.borderColor = `rgba(255, 0, 0, ${div.children.length / max})`;
});
```

```css
div {
  border: red 2px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 5px;
}

div > p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5</p>
  <p>6</p>
  <p>7</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>1</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
</div>
<div>
  <!-- nada -->
</div>
```

A ideia é usar a opacidade do `rgba`. Sabendo a div que tem mais descendentes podemos fazer as contas entre 0 e 1

Comment: A minha resposta recebeu um `-1`. Seria interessante saber porquê, no caso de haver algo errado na resposta :)

Comment: Blz @Sergio não entendi como sua resposta ficou igual a da foto que ele deu de exemplo, ja tiro o `-1` caso explique.